BGW Protocols - Number of Rounds
What does the depth mean in the case of BGW protocol? It says a depth $d$ requires $d$ rounds of communication while using the BGW protocol. Is it because multiplication requires interaction among parties? For example, what if we wanted to compute $x_1^3+ 3x_2^2+ 4x_3x_4$?

For a polynomial of degree p, you can compute it in depth d=log(p)
Roubd 1:
$x_1^2=x_1*x_1$
$x_2^2=x_2*x_2$
$x_3x_4=x_3*x_4$
Round 2:
$x_1^3=x_1^2*x_1$
Linear sum to get the result.
In general you can write your polynomial as a circuit and then just look at the depth.

Does degree d polynomial not require depth d circuit to compute

no, it does not.
you could compute $x^d$ by repeatedly multiplying with $x$ and you would get depth $d$ for degree $d$.
but instead you can use the square multiply algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring
